# Extracting Non-Digital "Signature" Images from PDF with iTextSharp

Tags: asp.net, .net, pdf, itext

I've been tasked with a project that needs to read the content of a PDF document with populated form fields and save the content to a database.  Once the data extracted I should be able to re-create the document using a master copy of the template and re-populated form field data.

Our user base will complete the form/template on a mobile device (specifically Android devices for our environment).  They will also be using the Adobe Acrobat Reader mobile app to complete the documents.  Once completed, each engineer working on the document will sign the document using the signature function in the mobile app (multiple signatures could be present on multiple pages) and submit the form (which currently emails a copy of the completed PDF to a specific email address).

Once I have a copy of the completed PDF document I am able to read the AcroForm fields using from a .NET application using the iTextSharp library and do whatever I need to do with it (store field "name" and "value" in a database)

```
Dim reader As PdfReader = New PdfReader(pdfBytes)
Dim pdfFormFields As AcroFields = reader.AcroFields
For Each formField In reader.AcroFields.Fields.Keys
    Dim ff As New FormField
    ff.Name = formField
    ff.Value = pdfFormFields.GetField(formField)
    Do_stuff_with(ff)
Next
```

I'm then able to re-populate the blank pdf template at a later stage with the form data, however am struggling to read the "signature" aspect of it embedded in the file.

When completed via the Acrobat Reader Android app I believe the "signature" isn't technically a signature in the proper "Digital Signature" sense that it can be read using the iTextSharp `AcroFields.GetSignatureNames()` or `AcroFields.GetSignatureDictionary` methods.  Instead I beleive the signature is stored as a `Stream` object within an `Annotation` in the document however I'm currently unable to read and convert this into a `Byte Array` to store in a database.
I know I will also need to get the page/position of each signature so that I can re-populate at a later stage.

I've tried several methods including extracting all Images from the document but this only extracts embedded images that existed in the template and not the annotation signatures.  With a blank dummy document containing just a submit button and signature I get an error after getting the dictionary object PdfName.RESOURCES as if nothing exists.

```
Dim pdf as New PdfReader(bytes)
For i As Int16 = 1 To pdf.NumberOfPages
    Dim pg As PdfDictionary = pdf.GetPageN(i)
    Dim res As PdfDictionary = CType(PdfReader.GetPdfObject(pg.Get(PdfName.RESOURCES)), PdfDictionary)
    ' ### 
    ' ### 
    ' ### Errors on next line with 
    ' ###     "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
    ' ### 
    ' ### 
    Dim xobj As PdfDictionary = CType(PdfReader.GetPdfObject(pg.Get(PdfName.XOBJECT)), PdfDictionary)
    If xobj IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each name As PdfName In xobj.Keys
            Dim obj As PdfObject = xobj.Get(name)
            If obj.IsIndirect Then
                Dim tg As PdfDictionary = CType(PdfReader.GetPdfObject(obj), PdfDictionary)
                Dim type As PdfName = CType(PdfReader.GetPdfObject(tg.Get(PdfName.SUBTYPE)), PdfName)
                If PdfName.IMAGE.Equals(type) Then
                    Dim xrefIdx As Integer = CType(obj, PRIndirectReference).Number
                    Dim pdfObj As PdfObject = pdf.GetPdfObject(xrefIdx)
                    Dim str As PdfStream = CType(pdfObj, PdfStream)
                    Dim bytes As Byte() = PdfReader.GetStreamBytesRaw(CType(str, PRStream))
                    Dim img As iTextSharp.text.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(CType(obj, PRIndirectReference))
                    Dim filter As String = tg.Get(PdfName.FILTER).ToString
                    If filter = "/DCTDecode" Then
                        Dim img2 As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(bytes))
                        Dim stream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream
                        img2.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
                        stream.Position = 0
                        PdfReader.KillIndirect(obj)
                        img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(stream)
                        writer.AddDirectImageSimple(img, CType(obj, PRIndirectReference))
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```

If I inspect the document with iText RUPS I can see two `Stream` objects ([Inspect1.png](https://test-dev-rfc3929-2018-02-21.ainscough.co.uk/Inspect1.png)) which I assume are the two signatures in my test document [TestDoc_Complete.pdf](https://test-dev-rfc3929-2018-02-21.ainscough.co.uk/TestDoc_Complete.pdf) but I'm unable to extract these either into a `Byte Array` or `Memory Stream` so that I can manipulate and save.

Any help (VB/C#) would be appreciated to help me solve this.

Thanks

---

### --EDIT--

I'm now able to loop through the `PdfObjects` using XrefSize and identify which objects are Streams.  I can read the Stream` Bytes and Raw Bytes and output these to a file but these are unreadable by any image viewer.

```
Dim pdf = New PdfReader(bytes)
Dim obj As PdfObject
For i As Integer = 1 To pdf.XrefSize
    Try
        obj = pdf.GetPdfObject(i)
        If obj IsNot Nothing And obj.IsStream Then
            Dim stream As PRStream = CType(obj, PRStream)
            Dim type As PdfName = Nothing
            Try
                type = CType(pdfreader.GetPdfObject(stream.Get(PdfName.FILTER)), PdfName)
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try

            If type IsNot Nothing And PdfName.FLATEDECODE.Equals(type) Then
                Dim b1 As Byte() = pdfreader.GetStreamBytes(stream)
                Dim b2 As Byte() = pdfreader.GetStreamBytesRaw(stream)
                csLog.AddLog("Stream Length: " & stream.Length, csLogging.DebugLevel.Debug)
                csLog.AddLog("bytes1 Length: " & b1.Length, csLogging.DebugLevel.Debug)
                csLog.AddLog("bytes2 Length: " & b2.Length, csLogging.DebugLevel.Debug)

                Dim fos As FileStream
                ' ### Write Bytes to file for testing
                fos = New FileStream(Server.MapPath(".") & "\bytes1" & i, FileMode.Create)
                fos.Write(b1, 0, b1.Length)
                fos.Flush()
                fos.Close()

                ' ### Write RawBytes to file for testing
                fos = New FileStream(Server.MapPath(".") & "\bytes2" & i, FileMode.Create)
                fos.Write(b2, 0, b2.Length)
                fos.Flush()
                fos.Close()


                ' ### CONVERSION ATTEMPTS
                ConvertAttempt1(b2, i)     ' ### Using Raw Bytes
                ConvertAttempt2(stream, i)

            End If
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
Next
```

The first file using `b1` appears to be a text representation of the `PRStream`
q
.160714 0 0 .160714 0 0 cm
0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 RG 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 rg 1 J 1 j 26.48880 w 488.00000 115.43372 m 488.00000 115.43372 l S 20.37600 w 184.00000 155.43372 m 184.00000 155.43372 184.00000 155.43372 182.44000 156.45367 c S 20.37600 w 
..... 
..... 
..... 
which I assume are the vector graphic curves/strokes.
The output of `b2` (raw bytes) has the same content length of the signatures I am expecting (3305 and 4834) as shown in the two sterams in iText RUPS.

I've attempted to convert the bytes to an image (JPG) but get errors

```
' ### Conversion attempt 1
Sub ConvertAttempt1(ByVal rawBytes As Byte(), ByVal xRef As Int16)
    Try
        Using memStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(rawBytes)
            memStream.Position = 0
            ' ###
            ' ###
            ' ### Falls over on next line - "Parameter is not valid"
            ' ###
            ' ###
            Dim img As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memStream)
            Dim path As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("."), String.Format("convert1_{0}.jpg", xRef))
            Dim parms As System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters = New System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters(1)
            parms.Param(0) = New System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Compression, 0)
            Dim jpegEncoder As System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo = GetImageEncoder("JPEG")
            img.Save(path, jpegEncoder, parms)
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        'csLog.AddLog(ex.Message, csLogging.DebugLevel.Errors)
        'csLog.AddLog(ex.StackTrace, csLogging.DebugLevel.Errors)
    End Try
End Sub
```

and

```
Sub ConvertAttempt2(ByVal stream As PRStream, ByVal xRef As Int16)
    ' ### Conversion attempt 2
    Try
        ' ###
        ' ###
        ' ### Falls over on next line - "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
        ' ###
        ' ###
        Dim pdfImage As PdfImageObject = New PdfImageObject(stream)
        Dim img As System.Drawing.Image = pdfImage.GetDrawingImage()
        Dim path As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("."), String.Format("convert2_{0}.jpg", xRef))
        Dim parms As System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters = New System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters(1)
        parms.Param(0) = New System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Compression, 0)
        Dim jpegEncoder As System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo = GetImageEncoder("JPEG")
        img.Save(path, jpegEncoder, parms)
    Catch ex As Exception
        csLog.AddLog(ex.Message, csLogging.DebugLevel.Errors)
        csLog.AddLog(ex.StackTrace, csLogging.DebugLevel.Errors)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: The signatures indeed are in those two streams you have identified, they are drawn using PDF vector graphics (paths consisting of curves which then are stroked). Thus, you have to put the stream contents into your database. The more difficult part is to find out where and at which scale they are drawn because that information is in the main page content streams. In your case it's still pretty easy because the instructions for drawing those two signature xobjects and only they are in the last content stream of the page. It is not clear to me, though, whether this will remain that simple...

Comment: *"I can read the Stream` Bytes and Raw Bytes and output these to a file but these are unreadable by any image viewer."* - After my previous comment that should have been obvious. There merely is a sequence of PDF path building and path stroking operations, nothing else. What image viewer would understand that...

Comment: Are you still working on that topic? If you are, are there still any open issues? How have you decided to store the signature streams? Are the signature streams also so easy to recognize?

Comment: Yes I'm still working on this.  I've not yet been able to insert the streams back into a new PDF document.